# Transmission aborts automated shut down.

Tags: shutdown, macos, torrent

My ISP offers unlimited downloads at a certain time period at night, but I don't want to wake up to shutdown my MBP 13.3 at that time. I tried to specify a certain shutdown time using the [Energy Saver option](http://lifehacker.com/282118/automatically-shut-down-and-boot-your-mac).

However, I found out to my utter dismay that **Transmisison needs to be explicitly** closed before it for the computer to shut down.

Comment: I assume you are using **Transmission**? Check this option in the Transmission preferences: **``Network->System Sleep``**

Comment: Well, I'm using Transmission! But the option says "Prevent computer from sleeping with active transfers" - I fear if i uncheck it, my MBP would goto sleep within moments of my leaving it, stalling my transfers long before the desired time. Are you sure this is a good idea ?

Comment: I'm sure this is necessary for the computer to shut down. Uncheck this option, then simply disable **``Computer sleep``** in the system settings for ``Energy Saver``. You do not have to disable **``Display Sleep``**.

Comment: @Matt - I found out I also need to uncheck "Prompt user for - Quit with active transfer" in Transmission for this to work. With that, it works like a charm!

Comment: Great to hear that. I'll add an answer then. I think we should also edit your question in order to clarify that this problem was linked to Transmission.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. In Transmission go to the preferences
2. uncheck **System sleep** under Network
   [image]
3. uncheck **Quit with active transfers** under General
   [image]